# How can I switch to another xib using uibutton?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, xib, tabbar

I have application with `TabBar` and four views (`FirstView.xib`, `SecondView.xib`, `ThirdView.xib`, `FourthView.xib`). In `ThirdView.xib` I have `UIButton`, when pressed, need to load a `FifthView.xib` with animation. How it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:"FifthView.xib" owner:nil options:nil];
for ( id object in array ) {
    if ( [object isMemberOfClass:[FifthView class]] ) {
        fifthView = (FifthView*)[object retain];
        break;
    }
}

...

[UIView transitionFromView:thirdView 
                    toView:fifthView
                  duration:1 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                completion:nil];
```

Comment: How can I connect this to button?

Comment: @Pavel, did you get this working? I seem to have missed this somehow.

Comment: No, I didn't(( I'm a newbie with this

Comment: Ok. Is `FifthView` a view class or a view controller class?

Comment: You need to create a method that is an IBAction and link the button's touchUpInside outlet to the IBAction on the Files'Owner in interface builder